# Epilogue endpoints are not being authenticated with passport

Tags: express, passport.js, sequelize.js, epilogue

My code is below and the `auth complete` never gets triggered. I'm not sure why since this is direct from the epilogue docs.

```
dataplan.list.auth((req, res, context) => {
  console.log('authenticating')
  // return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('auth with passport')
    passport.authenticate('jwt',{session: false}, function(err, user, info) {
      console.log('auth complete')
      if(err) {
        res.status(500);
        resolve(context.stop());
      }

      if(user) {
        resolve(context.continue());
      } else {
        context.error(new ForbiddenError());
      }
    });
  // }); 
})
```

Comment: FWIW, I used Epilogue on a project recently and regretted it. I found it buggy and the repo is no longer maintained (https://github.com/dchester/epilogue/issues/225) If you are at the beginning of your project, I suggest reconsidering using this library.

Comment: Switched to `finale-rest`, which seems to be more maintained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are returning a promise in your middleware function. It appears you were doing this but had it crossed out.

```
dataplan.list.auth((req, res, context) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', (err, user, expiry) => {
      if(err) {
        res.status(500);
        return resolve(context.stop());
      }

      if(user) {
        resolve(context.continue());
      } else {
        return resolve(context.error(new ForbiddenError()));
      }
    })(req, res);
  });
});
```